# Benefit of `contains[BB >: B](e: BB): Boolean` instead of `contains(e: Any): Boolean`

Tags: scala, standard-library, either

What's the benefit of defining `contains` as `contains[BB >: B](e: BB): Boolean` instead of `contains(e: Any): Boolean` in Scala.

[`Either.contains`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html#contains[BB>:B](elem:BB):Boolean) in the Scala standard library uses the first signature and I am unclear on the benefit of such a signature over the second signature.

Comment: type safety. passing something that isn't BB >: B will fail at compile time

Comment: @MrD I guess, the question is _how_ you can pass something that is not a superclass of `B`.  Everything is `Any`, and `Any` is a superclass of `B` ... There is no type, that this function would not accept AFAICS.

Comment: you can't pass something that isn't a superclass of B, thats kind of the point. So basically no subtypes of B. I think the reason for that is because there needs to be a properly defined == in B that can be used for comparision

Comment: @MrD There is nothing you can pass to `contains` that will fail to typecheck unless you explicitly provide a parameter type. Try it, you will see.

Comment: What boggles me is why you would ever want to pass something that's not a `B` to that function...

Comment: you can't actually pass a subtype of `B`, but it seems that way because if you do pass something that is a subtype scala treats it as `Any` and compares it as `Any`. I suppose the only reason for `contains` being type bound like that is just to prevent the `==` of a subtype of `B` from being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, none: the two signatures are equivalent. But it provides consistency with signatures of other members such as

```
 getOrElse[BB >: B](or: ⇒ BB): BB
```

For them, there is a difference because `BB` is part of the return type, so if we pass a `B`, we get `B` back, which we wouldn't have with `getOrElse(or: => Any): Any`.

> What boggles me is why you would ever want to pass something that's not a B to that function

You wouldn't. But `contains(e: B)` would not allow `Either` to be covariant. Try it, the compiler will reject it on the grounds that `B` appears in a contravariant position. Covariance means that e.g. `Either[A, SubtypeOfFoo]` is a subtype of `Either[A, Foo]`. So any call which is legal for `Either[A, Foo]` must be also legal for `Either[A, SubtypeOfFoo]`, and this includes `contains(Foo)`.